# Store the results of apply function in new column

Tags: r, apply

My data below

```
A<-c(1999,1999, 2001, 2001)
B<-c("A", "D", "A", "D")
df<-data.frame (A, B)
```

I am applying

```
df$C<-apply(df[1], 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 2000, 2000, x))
```

to create a new column with values based on a reference column

Output

```
     A B    C
1 1999 A 1999
2 1999 D 1999
3 2001 A 2000
4 2001 D 2000
```

Why it does replicate the same colname `A`and does not create column `C`?

Comment: Why do you need `apply` for a single column,  Just do `df$C <- df[,1];df[,3][df[,1] > 2000] <- 2000`

Comment: `df$C <- pmin(df$A, 2000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need an `apply` loop for a single column, it can be done with

```
 df$C  <- ifelse(df[,1] > 2000, 2000, df[,1])
```

---

In the OP's code, the output is a `matrix` with a single column and it also have the same column name resulting in a `matrix` column with dimnames as 'A'

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ A: num  1999 1999 2001 2001
#$ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","D": 1 2 1 2
#$ C: num [1:4, 1] 1999 1999 2000 2000
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr "A"
```

So, the column is already there, but it is a `matrix`

```
df$C
#      A
#[1,] 1999
#[2,] 1999
#[3,] 2000
#[4,] 2000
```

Instead of assigning a `matrix`, it should be converted to a `vector`

```
df$C <- as.vector(apply(df[1], 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 2000, 2000, x)))
df$C
#[1] 1999 1999 2000 2000
```